# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'retries' does not exist in type 'ProvidesCallback'. in tsc

Tags: typescript, cypress, typescript2.0, ts-jest

I just upgraded Cypress to version 5 and I would like to use retries on my test. The test file run fine with `cypress run --browser chrome --no-exit --spec test/test.spec.ts`

However I get the error after run command `tsc`. Does anyone know how can I fix the error?

```sh
$ tsc
test/test.spec.ts:3:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ retries: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ProvidesCallback'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'retries' does not exist in type 'ProvidesCallback'.

3   it('test on it', {retries: 1}, () => {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

.eslintrc.json

```json
{
  "extends": ["plugin:cypress/recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "env": {
    "cypress/globals": true
  },
  "plugins": ["cypress", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "root": true,
}
```

test/test.spec.ts

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('test on it', {retries: 1}, () => {
    cy.wrap('2').should('eq', '3');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html#Global-Configuration) you should put these lines in config.json, after you upgrade to version 5+

```
{
  "retries": {
    "runMode": 2,
    "openMode": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you do this from the command line? for instance --config retries=0

Comment: I suppose you can but havem\n`t tryed it since I prefer to ceep those variables as config file

Comment: I agree, unfortunately  in my employer's config they want the retry, I want to override it at the command line, I am going to figure it out, I will get back to you